# What search engine does OpenText Content Server 10.x use?

Tags: opentext, livelink

I'm working on a project with an older version of Content Server and am looking to integrate C.S. search with another portal via federated search.

Answer (score 0):

It's the "Opentext Search Engine". All versions from 10.5 on use the same engine.
There is an HTTP API available for integration.

To access the documentation you (or your customer) need to login on https://knowledge.opentext.com, search for `search api programming guide` and you shall be enlightened.